# yahoo messenger status checker code?

Tags: status, client-server, yahoo-messenger

I saw a lot of web sites out there that are capable of checking the status of a person on yahoo messenger, namely if that person is available, invisible or offline.
I have something in mind, but I need to know the method they used to achieve this. 
made my homework and searched all over google, but found nothing.

Does anyone know anything about this? maybe a tutorial or a source code?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could help: http://www.phpclasses.org/package/5457-PHP-Check-the-online-status-of-an-Yahoo-messenger-user.html

Comment: yeah, it tells me if the user is online or offline, but it doesn't make the difference between invisible or offline status. do you have any other idea? :)